# PHP and MYSQL query to pull duplicates from multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am logging information from a threads page on my forum,  in 4 days there has been nearly 400,000 entries and one SQL query is using 12 seconds, i need help to reduce the query run time if possible or use php to calculate the guests views for each thread_id

I have the following mysql Table and Columns

```
thread_count

count_id thread_id user_id timestamp ip_address
```

I have manged to get the weekly stats in 0.2 seconds for threads with over 100 views using this query

```
SELECT thread_id, timestamp, user_id, COUNT(thread_id) AS cnt FROM thread_count GROUP BY thread_id HAVING COUNT( thread_id) >100 AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 7 ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The **problem** is when I try to run this query to find out how many guests views there has been

```
$guestcount = SELECT user_id, thread_id, COUNT(user_id) AS cntg FROM thread_count WHERE user_id =0 AND thread_id = ".$array['thread_id']."
```

That is run in a while loop from the first query

This second query takes 12.9 seconds to run

This is the while loop from the php code,  its vbulletin so might look strange

```
while ($array = $db->fetch_array($threadsql)){

                $thread_title = $db->fetch_array($vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT title FROM thread WHERE threadid = ".$array['thread_id'].""));

            //  $guestcount = $db->fetch_array($vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT user_id, thread_id, COUNT(user_id) AS cntg FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread_count WHERE user_id =0 AND thread_id = ".$array['thread_id'].""));

                $weekly .= '<tr><td><a href="showthread.php?t='.$array['thread_id'].'">'.$array['thread_id'].'</a></td>
                <td>'.$array['cnt'].' </td> <td><a href="showthread.php?t='.$array['thread_id'].'">'.$thread_title[title].'</a></td><td>Username Here</td> <td>'.$guestcount[cntg].'</td> </tr>';               

            }
```

Basically guests hits are stored as **0** in the **user_id** column,  I did try this and not use the 12 second query but it just shows me 0

```
foreach($array as $guest){
                if ($array[user_id] = 0 && $thread[thread_id] = $array[thread_id])
                            $guestcount = count($guest);
                }
```

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Comment: How can I reduce the second query  (where I highlighted the word PROBLEM

Comment: If this is a PHP question, include some PHP code.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce"?

Comment: OK doing that now

Comment: 1. What is "thread_mick_count " ? is it a view?
2. Did you try to check execution plan for the slow query?

Comment: Hi Yossi,  Sorry that was a previous table I called it,  the table is called thread_count -  what is an execution plan ?

Comment: @MarkDavis execution plan is an explanation of "how the database is going to execute the query". Basically you can see in what order your query will execute, which (if any) indexes will be used, and so on.

in MySQL, you can write EXPLAIN and the query, and you'll get the execution plan. check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: I have a feeling because the query is in a while loop - looping from the first query I posted,  it then runs the 12 second query around 100 times on a database with more than 400,000 entries.  I think I need a php solution using the first query.

Comment: so the 12 seconds is 100 executions of the query or one?

Comment: it's doing it 100+ times in the while loop,  I am looking at the array_count function in php to count the user_id when thread_id has duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an SQL solution. Specifically, since you run two different aggregations, use derived tables to return *thread_id*, *cnt*, *title*, and *cntg* fields all in one query call with nested looping.

Also, unfortunately, like some MySQL developers you are not running valid ANSI SQL as `GROUP BY` must include all non-aggregated columns and hence your original queries should fail. Likely, you have MySQL's [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode off (defaults to on as of version 5.7.5). Below queries are adjusted to be fully compliant SQL, portable to other RDBMS's.

```sql
SELECT t.thread_id, t.cnt, h.title, g.cntg

FROM
  (SELECT c.thread_id, COUNT(c.thread_id) AS cnt 
   FROM thread_count c
   WHERE c.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 24 * 3600 * 7 
   GROUP BY c.thread_id 
   HAVING COUNT(c.thread_id) > 100
  ) As t 

INNER JOIN    
 (SELECT c.thread_id, COUNT(c.user_id) AS cntg 
  FROM thread_count c
  WHERE c.user_id=0 
  GROUP BY c.thread_id
 ) As g
ON t.thread_id = g.thread_id

INNER JOIN 
  thread h
ON h.threadid = t.thread_id

ORDER BY t.cnt DESC
```

Comment: This is brilliant thank you so much.  I am looking to order it by **cnt**  I tried>  ORDER BY cnt DESC  **after** As t  but it gave me MySQL error

Comment: Place the `ORDER BY` in outer query at very end. See edit.